# Exploring embedded derby database using IntelliJ DB Navigator Plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, derby

I have created an in-memory Derby database (created with maven plugin). I am looking for a way to explore the database like how DB Navigator does with oracle/mysql databases.

PS: I am very new to work with embedded databases. I am only using to write unit tests on my DAOs

Comment: I created a Derby instance, tried to populate the table with some random data. I am trying to see if I will be able to query on the table that I have populated.

Comment: You said "in-memory" in your question, I assume you mean your JDBC Connection URL begins `jdbc:derby:memory:...` This means that the database contents are **only** available to that particular Java app while it is running; when the app exits, the database vanishes.

Comment: yup, my URL begins with `jdbc:derby:memory:..` I am trying to query it in my app (in my unit tests).

Comment: From within your same app, you are allowed to open multiple JDBC connections to the same `jdbc:derby:memory:...` URL, and execute SQL queries, and read the results, etc.